# GRUB-Problem – Ubuntu on SSD, Windows on HDD

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd, gparted

I googled alot but didn't find a solution for my certain problem.

I installed windows and ubuntu on my SSD and used my HDD as a NTFS to be able to save data to it from both Windows and Linux.

Now I decided to completely delete Windows from the SSD and to put it on the HDD as a new partition.

I made two screenshots out of gparted to show you my current partitions.

[image: SSD]

[image: HDD]

Starting the computer a alert says that it didnt find a boot loader or something.

What would you recommend me to do to be able to choose Ubuntu (sda5) and Windows7 (sdb6) in a Boot loader (f.e. GRUB)?

Thanks for any help!

PS: I am currently using a Live-CD of Ubuntu, which I could use to install GRUB, I think.

Comment: switch sata cables between the two hard disks